# Problem with const qualifiers to get private atributes of an object

Tags: c++, constructor, constants, copy-constructor

I'm a completely new to C++ and I'm having a very stupid problem.

I have a Graph class and I need to create a copy constructor for it. This is my class:

```
#include <igraph.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Graph { 
public:
  Graph(int N); // contructor
  ~Graph();     // destructor
  Graph(const Graph& other); // Copy constructor 
  igraph_t * getGraph();
  int getSize();

private:
  igraph_t graph;
  int size;
};
```

There's a function `int igraph_copy(igraph_t * to, const igraph_t * from)` in `igraph.h` that copies an `igraph_t` type adequately.

The constructor and destructor are trivial and work normally, and I have the following copy constructor:

```
Graph :: Graph(const Graph& other) {
  igraph_t * otherGraph = other.getGraph();
  igraph_copy(&graph, otherGraph);
  size = other.getSize();

}

igraph_t * Graph :: getGraph(){ 
  return &graph;
}

int Graph :: getSize() {
  return size;
}
```

When I compile this, I got the following errors:

```
calsaverini@Ankhesenamun:~/authC/teste$ make
g++ -I/usr/include/igraph -L/usr/local/lib -ligraph -c foo.cpp -o foo.o
foo.cpp: In copy constructor ‘Graph::Graph(const Graph&)’:
foo.cpp:30: error: passing ‘const Graph’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘igraph_t* Graph::getGraph()’ discards qualifiers
foo.cpp:32: error: passing ‘const Graph’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘int Graph::getSize()’ discards qualifiers
make: *** [foo.o] Error 1
```

I feel this must be something very basic I didn't get about what the const qualifier means.

I don't really know C++ (and I really don't know C that much deeply, for that matter...) but I need to mess with code made by people who do. :(

Any clues or remarks about this copy constructor will be also very humbly appreciated. :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `getGraph` function needs to be declared with the `const` qualifier:

`const igraph_t* getGraph() const { ... }`

This is because `other` is a constant reference.  When an object or reference is constant, you can only call member functions of that object which are declared with the `const` qualifier.  (The `const` which appears *after* the function name and parameter list.)

Note that this also requires you to return a constant pointer.

It's common in C++ to write two "get" functions, one which is constant and the other non-constant, in order to deal with both cases.  So you could declare two getGraph() functions:

`const igraph_t* getGraph() const { ... }`

...and

`igraph_t* getGraph() { ... }`

The first will be called if the object is constant, and the second will be called if the object is non-constant.  You should probably read more about the [const member-function qualifier](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.10), as well as [const-correctness](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.1) in general.